# Is it possible to expose an EJB project as a RESTful WS?

Tags: rest, ejb-3.0, jax-rs, distributed-computing

I have implemented a RESTful web service using jersey and deployed it on Tomcat, I have used DAO classes to manipulate database operations, entities to wrap database records. and did the processing in separate package. I want to make this system distributed using EJB. First of all would it be easy to do this change. or i need to rewrite things from scratch. Second, I still need to have the REST WS, so would it be possible to expose the EJB as a REST WS and how? would the REST WS be in the same EJB project or in a different one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do it as an EJB and REST WS.  Upgrade your Tomcat install to [TomEE Plus](http://tomee.apache.org), then just add `@Stateless` or `@Singleton` to the existing REST service.

You won't need Jersey in there anymore as the Java EE version of Tomcat (TomEE) includes CXF for JAX-RS support.

This example is not well documented, but shows a functional application that combines both EJB and JAX-RS.

http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/rest-on-ejb/README.html

Comment: and i still need to change the DAOs and entities into session and entity beans respectively. Is that correct?

Comment: It's up do you how much you convert. How you persist data and how you expose your services are two different decisions.  You can have an EJB that exposes itself as a REST WS and `@Local` and `@Remote` bean regardless if you use JPA or some other technology for persistence.